# Cannot login to fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install

Tags: system-installation, usb

After the grub menu following a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 installation I have the following and I cannot proceed further:

[image]

Comment: When you downloaded the ISO did you verify it before making the boot device? See this site https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Yes i verified the ISO

Answer (score 0):

I had to unplug every usb device (apart from mouse / keyboard) on my system to be able to reach a login screen.

I was hoping that system update would resolve the issue but this is not the case.